# Base ng-disabled on input rather than form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to disable a button next to my input box if that input is `$invalid`. If I was disabling this button based on the validity of an entire form I would simply use `ng-disabled="formName.$invalid"`. How would I accomplish the same task but based on just one input field?

```
<td>
  <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="points.limit">
</td>
<td>
  <button class="btn btn-limit btn-success" ng-click='points.setLimit(points.limit)' ng-disabled="?">Save</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Without a form to access form inputs from, you won't be able to check validity. You need a form with a name and you need the inputs to have names in order to access them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `name` attribute for `ng-model="points.limit"` element so that it would be have an part of `formName`. Also after declaring the `name` attribute on element you could have access to that form element using `formName.limit`, You could also get this object inside a scope.

**Markup**

```
<td>
    <input type="number" name="limit" min="0" ng-model="points.limit">
</td>
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-limit btn-success" ng-click='points.setLimit(points.limit)' 
     ng-disabled="formName.limit.$invalid">
      Save
    </button>
</td>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with lone inputs? My inputs are not part of a form so I have no `formName` to use.

Comment: @MattDionis what do you mean by `loan` inputs, could you bit elaborate on that..also do look at my edit..

Comment: I simply mean that there is no form in my HTML, so I have no `formName` to reference in `formName.limit.$invalid`.

Comment: @MattDionis you to use form element which does provide the element validation thing..

Answer (score 0):

Give the input a name like so:

`<input name="limit" type="number" min="0" ng-model="points.limit">`

and then you can disable the button like so:

`<button class="btn btn-limit btn-success" ng-click='points.setLimit(points.limit)' ng-disabled="theForm.limit.$invalid">Save</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Since the model's value becomes undefined when it is invalid, one solution would be to use that to determine validity since you aren't using a form.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <body>
    <input name="abc" type="number" min="0" ng-model="points.limit">
    <button ng-click='points.setLimit(points.limit)' ng-disabled="points.limit === undefined">Save</button>
  </body>
</html>
```